# Why does Azure Data Factory seemingly insist on inserting DateTimes as string?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to set up an Azure Data Factory to copy and denormalize my data from a AzureSQL database to another AzureSQL database for reporting/BI purposes with a data flow, but I ran into a problem with inserting dates.

This is the definition of my dataflow.

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "script": "\n\nsource(output(\n\t\tBucketId as string,\n\t\tStreamId as string,\n\t\tStreamIdOriginal as string,\n\t\tStreamRevision as integer,\n\t\tItems as integer,\n\t\tCommitId as string,\n\t\tCommitSequence as integer,\n\t\tCommitStamp as timestamp,\n\t\tCheckpointNumber as long,\n\t\tDispatched as boolean,\n\t\tHeaders as binary,\n\t\tPayload as binary\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tisolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',\n\tformat: 'table') ~> source1\nsource1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'table',\n\tdeletable:false,\n\tinsertable:true,\n\tupdateable:false,\n\tupsertable:false,\n\tmapColumn(\n\t\tBucketId,\n\t\tCommitStamp\n\t)) ~> sink1"
        }
    }
}
```

and these are the definitions of my source

```
{
    "name": "AzureSqlTable1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "Source_Test",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "schema": [
            {
                "name": "BucketId",
                "type": "varchar"
            },
            {
                "name": "StreamId",
                "type": "char"
            },
            {
                "name": "StreamIdOriginal",
                "type": "nvarchar"
            },
            {
                "name": "StreamRevision",
                "type": "int",
                "precision": 10
            },
            {
                "name": "Items",
                "type": "tinyint",
                "precision": 3
            },
            {
                "name": "CommitId",
                "type": "uniqueidentifier"
            },
            {
                "name": "CommitSequence",
                "type": "int",
                "precision": 10
            },
            {
                "name": "CommitStamp",
                "type": "datetime2",
                "scale": 7
            },
            {
                "name": "CheckpointNumber",
                "type": "bigint",
                "precision": 19
            },
            {
                "name": "Dispatched",
                "type": "bit"
            },
            {
                "name": "Headers",
                "type": "varbinary"
            },
            {
                "name": "Payload",
                "type": "varbinary"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "tableName": "[dbo].[Commits]"
        }
    }
}
```

and sink data sets

```
{
    "name": "AzureSqlTable2",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "Dest_Test",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "schema": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "tableName": "dbo.Test2"
        }
    }
}
```

When running my pipeline with the data flow I get the following error:

```
Activity dataflow1 failed: DF-EXEC-1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:256)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:108)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:28)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.doInsertBulk(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1611)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.access$200(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:58)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy$1InsertBulk.doExecute(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:709)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.sendBulkLoadBCP(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:739)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1684)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:669)
    at com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect.DataFrameFunctions.com$microsoft$azure$sqldb$spark$connect$DataFrameFunctions$$bulkCopy(DataFrameFunctions.scala:127)
    at com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$bulkCopyToSqlDB$1.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:72)
    at com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$bulkCopyToSqlDB$1.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2226)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2226)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1401)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My Azure SQL audit log shows the following statement that failed (which is not a huge surprise considering that it uses `VARCHAR(50)` as type for `[CommitStamp]`:

```
INSERT BULK dbo.T_301fcb5e4a4148d4a48f2943011b2f04 (
  [BucketId] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
  [CommitStamp] VARCHAR(50), 
  [StreamId] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
  [StreamIdOriginal] NVARCHAR(MAX),
  [StreamRevision] INT,
  [Items] INT,
  [CommitId] NVARCHAR(MAX),
  [CommitSequence] INT, 
  [CheckpointNumber] BIGINT, 
  [Dispatched] BIT,
  [Headers] VARBINARY(MAX),
  [Payload] VARBINARY(MAX),
  [r8e440f7252bb401b9ead107597de6293] INT) 
with (ROWS_PER_BATCH = 4096, TABLOCK)
```

I have absolutely no idea why this occurs. It looks like the schema information is correct but somehow it seems the data factory/data flow wants to insert the `CommitStamp` as a string type.

As requested, the output from the data flow/code/plan view:

```
source(output(
        BucketId as string,
        StreamId as string,
        StreamIdOriginal as string,
        StreamRevision as integer,
        Items as integer,
        CommitId as string,
        CommitSequence as integer,
        CommitStamp as timestamp,
        CheckpointNumber as long,
        Dispatched as boolean,
        Headers as binary,
        Payload as binary
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',
    format: 'table',
    schemaName: '[dbo]',
    tableName: '[Commits]',
    store: 'sqlserver',
    server: 'sign2025-sqldata.database.windows.net',
    database: 'SignPath.Application',
    user: 'Sign2025Admin',
    password: '**********') ~> source1
source1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    format: 'table',
    deletable:false,
    insertable:true,
    updateable:false,
    upsertable:false,
    mapColumn(
        BucketId,
        CommitStamp
    ),
    schemaName: 'dbo',
    tableName: 'Test2',
    store: 'sqlserver',
    server: 'sign2025-sqldata.database.windows.net',
    database: 'SignPath.Reporting',
    user: 'Sign2025Admin',
    password: '**********') ~> sink1
```

Comment: Any other difference between Source table and Sink table schema except [CommitStamp] data type?

Comment: Actually the Sink table has no predefined schema (it is supposed to be created by ADF on the fly), however, I also tried using a fixed schema (identical to the Source table) and that did not work as well.

Comment: Hi @chrischu, please see my answer, I tried and convert the datetime2 to  varcahr() successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a data flow to copy data from an Azure SQL database to another Azure SQL database. It succeeded to covert `datatime2` to `VARCHAR(50)`.

This is the definition of my dataflow:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DestinationDataset_sto",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DestinationDataset_mex",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "script": "\n\nsource(output(\n\t\tID as integer,\n\t\ttName as string,\n\t\tmyTime as timestamp\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tisolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',\n\tformat: 'table') ~> source1\nsource1 sink(input(\n\t\tID as integer,\n\t\ttName as string,\n\t\tmyTime as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'table',\n\tdeletable:false,\n\tinsertable:true,\n\tupdateable:false,\n\tupsertable:false) ~> sink1"
        }
    }
}
```

The definitions of my source:

```
{
    "name": "DestinationDataset_sto",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "schema": [
            {
                "name": "ID",
                "type": "int",
                "precision": 10
            },
            {
                "name": "tName",
                "type": "varchar"
            },
            {
                "name": "myTime",
                "type": "datetime2",
                "scale": 7
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "tableName": "[dbo].[demo]"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

My sink settings:

```
{
    "name": "DestinationDataset_mex",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "schema": [
            {
                "name": "ID",
                "type": "int",
                "precision": 10
            },
            {
                "name": "tName",
                "type": "varchar"
            },
            {
                "name": "myTime",
                "type": "varchar"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "tableName": "[dbo].[demo1]"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

Here are my data flow steps.
[image]

**Step 1: Source settings:**
[image]
[image]

**Step 2: Sink  settings:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Running succeeded:
[image]

The table demo and demo1 almost have the same schema except the `myTime`.

My source table and it's data:

[image]

My sink table and the data copied from `demo`:

[image]

Data Flow plan:

```
source(output(
        ID as integer,
        tName as string,
        myTime as timestamp
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: true,
    isolationLevel: 'SERIALIZABLE',
    format: 'table',
    schemaName: '[dbo]',
    tableName: '[demo]',
    store: 'sqlserver',
    server: '****.database.windows.net',
    database: '****',
    user: 'ServerAdmin',
    password: '**********') ~> source1
source1 sink(input(
        ID as integer,
        tName as string,
        myTime as string
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    format: 'table',
    deletable:false,
    insertable:true,
    updateable:false,
    upsertable:false,
    schemaName: '[dbo]',
    tableName: '[demo1]',
    store: 'sqlserver',
    server: '****.database.windows.net',
    database: '****',
    user: 'ServerAdmin',
    password: '**********') ~> sink1
```

**Update1:**

I create the sink table manually and found that:

> Data Flow  can convert `datatime2`  to `VARCHAR()`(maybe `NVARCHAR()`) , `date` ,`datetimeoffset`.

When I try the date type `time`, `datetime`, `datetime2`, `smalldatetime`, Data Flow always gives the error:

```
"message": "DF-EXEC-1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
```

**Update 2019-7-11:**

I asked Azure Support for help and they replied me: this is a bug of Data Flow and there is no solution for now.
[image]

**Update 2019-7-12:**

I tested with Azure Support and they conform this is a bug. Here is the new email:
[image]

They also told me that the **fix is already made and it will be deployed in next deployment train. This could be end of next week**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, but my point is: I want to have the same data type (datetime2) in the sink. Reducing it to a string type is not an option for me as I want to process the data further and I want to keep the data model as expressive as possible.

Comment: We're taking a look at why we're writing the column as nvarchar ... Can you do me a favor? Go to the Code button on your data flow UI and then click Plan. Copy and paste the formatted script here. Thx!

Comment: @chrischu I  tested according the error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". In your source table [CommitStamp] is `datetime2`, and the [CommitStamp] in your sink table you want to create  is `VARCHAR(50)`.

Comment: @MarkKromer I added the requested code to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @chrischu The error still exist now? I compared our code, they are almost same.

Comment: The error still exists, yes. Your code differs from mine, since you use a fixed sink schema, while mine uses a dynamic one and in the fact that your sink schema uses varchar instead of datetime2 (which is not desireable).

Comment: @chrischu I will test again.

Comment: @chrischu  I tested and found that you also can use the date or datetimeoffset in sink table.  And for this question, I asked Azure Support and waiting for the reply.

Comment: This is a bug of Data Flow.

Comment: If I understand the Azure support reply correctly, they are not yet admitting that it is a bug, they are just saying that they will investigate and that they ask you to agree that the issue is done if one of the four mentioned possibilities comes to pass.

Comment: @chrischu But these four answers all shows that it's a bug and has no solution. I have provided my failed active run ID for Azure Support.

Comment: Yes but they are saying that if they arrive at one of those for outcomes it will be considered done, BUT they cannot know if they arrive there. Its like throwing a ball in a random direction and saying: if I hit a person I will have won and then deducing that you'll always hit a person.

Comment: @chrischu The bug is Data Flow only can convert one row dataime2 data. I tested with Azure Support to confirm the error.  They will send me an new Email and try to solve the problem. You can completely trust this. You also can test this in your computer.

Comment: So you're saying that if there is only one row with a datetime2 it works, but as soon as there are 2 rows it doesn't? I cannot reproduce that behavior on my system :O.

Comment: So you always get the error no matter how many datetime2 data. For now, you can use 'date' or`datetimeoffset` to make your Data Flow works until Azure ADF engineer team fix the bug.

Comment: This morning we have tested more details. Data flow support convert  datetime to datetime2 well. If your source table has more data, change the data type is not good for you.

Comment: @chrischu If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Sink dataset defines myTime as a String:

sink(input(
        ID as integer,
        tName as string,
        myTime as string
    )

Can you change that to timestamp or Date, whichever you'd like to land it as?

Alternatively, you can land the data in a temporary staging table in SQL by setting "Recreate table" on the Sink and let ADF generate a new table definition on the fly using the data types of your mapped fields in the data flow.

Comment: This answer refers to the code posted by Leon Yue right? In my code I couldn't find any reference to the `sink(input(....` code you mentioned.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to set the "Recreate table" setting, but unfortunately that does not change anything (just tested it with "Recreate table" set) :(.